# RegEx Tomar la declaración de funciones de python

Tags: java, python, regex, compilador, jflex

Estoy haciendo un analizador léxico en java y tomé como lenguaje a analizar **`python`**, y estoy tratando de declarar mediante **`jflex`** la mayoría de código que se puede llegar a ocupar, el **`regex`** de comentarios, variables, etc ya funciona

Pero para las funciones que son creadas por uno mismo el sistema me devuelve

`variable`, `abre paréntesis`, `variable`, `cierra paréntesis`

y debería devolver, `función manual`, `abre paréntesis`, `variable`, `cierra paréntesis`

y no encuentro como capturarlo ahí.

**`{NOMBRE_FUNCION} {lexeme=yytext(); return DECLARACION_FUNCION;}`**

con esto declaro las funciones que comienzan con **`def`**

**`def hola(dato)`**, lo capturo con el anterior

pero para algo tipo

**`imprime(dato)`** que se cree específicamente para el momento no puedo tomar bien el dato

[image: Imagen de prueba del código]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Desconozco Jflex, y sus expresiones regulares son un poco diferentes a lo que estoy acostumbrado, pero probablemente tendrías que definir una regla que te mire un nombre precedido por paréntesis. Si no quieres que esa regla te capture los paréntesis, puedes utilizar una búsqueda hacia adelante (lookahead), que busca pero no captura.

Según la [documentación](http://jflex.de/manual.html), parece que con Jflex el lookahead se hace con la barra.

Así pues podrías probar con algo similar a esto:

`USA_FUNCION = [a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9_]*/"("`

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu tiempo, de hecho si, en mis experimentos, busquedas y demás llegué a algo similar y funcionó, en cualquier caso tu respuesta fue la mas acertada

Comment: Gracias, si sirvió podrías marcarla como "aceptada" Si por el contrario no acaba de ajustarse a la pregunta, podrías añadir tú mismo la respuesta y marcar la casilla "wiki de comunidad", y aceptarla

Comment: Listo, gracias, la he marcado ya que si era eso lo que debía hacerse, aunque la arme yo por partes, pero era eso.

Answer (score 0):

puedes intentar con esto:

```
ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("py");
Object result = engine.eval(python_code);
```

Comment: https://pastebin.com/V7TYyePd mira, te dejo el codigo que tengo en el archivo analizador.flex que es donde voy creando los tokens